# Objective-C probe a bluetooth device that requires a pairing code but that has horrible/opaque docs

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am trying to write an app to connect to a bluetooth medical device. The company that makes the device sent me a 300 page manual and basically told me to read all of it. I did an exploratory peripheral detection with CoreBluetooth and found the following device info:

```
centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:
(null) with {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 0;
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <8c0001e2 91d3a2d4 eb1f2417 da260263 3acf359c 3c206159 09>;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        FEFD
    );
```

I then tried searching the pdf the company provided me for `FEFD` thinking that was the service identifier and would help me find the juicy bits of the manual...no dice.

This is my first bluetooth project, and I'm wondering how to go through this most efficiently. I need to pair with the device with an authorization code, and then I need to retrieve the measurements on the device. Is there any chance I can simply probe the device with Core Bluetooth. How would an experience bluetooth programmer go about this?

thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can use the LightBlue app from the App Store to connect and see what is has in terms of services and characteristics.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks a lot for this tip!

Comment: did you find any code to pair BLE devices ?

Answer (score 0):

(I think it should be comment, but I can't write them yet.)

You can use **Hardware IO Tools for XCode**. You can install it from Apple Developer pages. It has something called Bluetooth Explorer and could be really helpful with probing bluetooth devices. I don't know if it will be able to help in your case (medical equipment), but it was really nice tool when I used it with simple Bluetooth devices.

It's program for Mac, so your Mac has to have Bluetooth module to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip!